# Get next and previous records in an ordered list

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using PHP to parse a sorted list of records and get the previous and next record of a given record. My DB has grown a lot and the query is taking too much time.

I'd like to change the query so that it only returns the previous and next records and also takes less time. Maybe I need to add an index.

Here's the current query :

```
SELECT id 
  FROM events 
 WHERE latitude BETWEEN 48.772559580567 AND 48.952423619433 
   AND longitude BETWEEN 2.2154977888952 AND 2.4889022111048 
 ORDER 
    BY start_time ASC
     , id
```

I have to sort by start_time & id since several events can start at the same time. I have to use a sort so that the list is constant and next & prev buttons always use the same algorithm.

This currently takes between 0.1 and 0.4 seconds which is way too long. And then I need to parse in PHP the 6000 returned rows to get the next and previous records.

I've read many similar topics but none of them seemed to address speed. Mostly I've found "min(id) FROM ... WHERE recordid > targetid UNION max(id) FROM ... WHERE recordid < targetid" which means doubling the 0.1 to 0.4 seconds.

Schema of the DB :

- id int(11)
- latitude double
- longitude double
- start_time timestamp

indexes :

- id PRIMARY
- latitude
- longitude
- latitude+longitude

Comment: Provide your db schema, please, including your indexes.

Comment: I've added it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add a single index for both latitude AND longitude (just as Strawberry suggests)? `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD INDEX coordinates (latitude, longitude);`

Comment: But are they separate indexes, or one compound index? Also, this is possibly DECIMAL, not DOUBLE?

Comment: Oui, oui, c'est Paris. I've added an index on both values but to no change I'm afraid. Still 0.1 to 0.3 seconds. I've also removed the WHERE condition and since it SELECTs all records but needs to sort the list, the query response is between 0.2 to 0.3 seconds due to the number of records to select and then sort I guess.